# PLease assist with my JTable Loop Exception

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is my code where I'm trying to loop through all the rows in my new stock table. Even when I use totalRows - 1 I still get the same exeption. Any help will be appreciated.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
int totalRows = newTable.getRowCount();
String tempName = "";
int tempTotal = 0;
System.out.println("total new rows: " + totalRows);

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < (totalRows - 1); i++) {
            tempName = currentTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
            tempTotal = Integer.parseInt(currentTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            System.out.println("Current Table Product:    " + currentTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            System.out.println("Current Table Total:  " + currentTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1).toString());

            System.out.println("New Table Product:    " + newTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            System.out.println("New Table Temp Total:  " + newTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1).toString());

            //if (newTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString() == currentTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString()) {
            //    int newTempTotal = Integer.parseInt(newTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            //    newTotal = newTempTotal + tempTotal;
            //    System.out.println("product:    " + newTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            //    System.out.println("grand new total:    " + newTotal);
            //}
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I get the following exception...

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at great.meat.AddNewStock.jButton1ActionPerformed(AddNewStock.java:325)
at great.meat.AddNewStock.access$300(AddNewStock.java:23)
at great.meat.AddNewStock$4.actionPerformed(AddNewStock.java:210)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
```

Comment: does the `newTable`have the same count of rows as `currentTable` ?

Comment: yes for now it has the same number of rows

Comment: does the `newTable.getModel()` have the same count of rows as `currentTable.getModel()`

Comment: yes newTable and curentTable has the same amount of rows

Comment: I specifically asked for their model row count, not the JTable

Comment: @jhamoni no its not, newTable has 70, I see now where my issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many rows both tables have, but your problem could be in this line:

```
tempName = currentTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
```

because you are looping using the newTable row count:

```
int totalRows = newTable.getRowCount();
```

but you're trying to get the data from currentTable. If currentTable has less rows than newTable then it will throw an exception.

Comment: That was exactly it, my new table had more rows than my current table, thank you